# How to drop row in pandas DataFrame by row index number

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop some rows with does match with if conditions in my code, but it can not , it pop out the error as below , could you please help assist ?

```
def listconvert(df_test):
    df1 = []
    for i in df_test:
        if str(i) != 'nan':
            df1.append(i)
    return df1


for j in range(len(df)-1):
    # print(len(listconvert(df.iloc[j].values)) )
    if len(listconvert(df.iloc[j].values)) < len(df.columns):
        # df.drop(df.loc[df.index==j].index,inplace=True)
        print(len(listconvert(df.iloc[j].values)))
        df = df.drop(df.index[j])
    else:
        pass
# df1.to_excel("Mar-131.xlsx")
```

the error as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16140/2461102218.py in <module>
     45 for j in range(len(df)-1):
     46     # print(len(listconvert(df.iloc[j].values)) )
---> 47     if len(listconvert(df.iloc[j].values)) < len(df.columns):
     48         # df.drop(df.loc[df.index==j].index,inplace=True)
     49         print(len(listconvert(df.iloc[j].values)))

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: Loops like this are dead slow in Pandas.  Do you care about performance?  If not, just use a Python list instead of a DataFrame.  If yes, show us what `listconvert` does.

Comment: Hi @JohnZwinck , just update function listconvert , this is a part in the whole process, i write to drop these unwanted row in my df, btw , i have solved it by create a list contain all the index of rows which i need to drop , then use a for loop to drop them. btw, very appreciate if you have a better solution for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rethink your code.  Fundamentally all it's doing is dropping rows which contain one or more NANs.  You can do that 1000x faster like this:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Or, just for inspiration to show how you could do it yourself if there weren't a prebuilt function for it:

```
df = df[df.notna().all(axis=1)]
```

That's it, that replaces all the code you had, with no slow `for` loops.

Comment: just tried it , it drop all row in my df  haha , i want to keep some row (in these row still have cell empty, not fill all) , in my case can not use notna() function.